# Craft Commerce - For a discount, can we include all products in the product count but not include the sale items that receive the discount?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

What I would like is for a 10% discount to be applied to non sale items after the total cart quantity reaches 10 total items. I would ONLY like this discount on non sale items. Is that possible?

So, say I have 2 Products in my cart:

- Item A - $20 on sale for $10, qty 9
- Item B - $20, qty 1

This makes my total in cart quantity 10 line items even though 9 of them are sale items.

What I would like is for `Item B` to be discounted 10% making my cart total `$108`

```
( (10*9) + (20 * .9) ) = 108
```

As it currently stands, if I toggle `Exclude this discount for products that are already on sale` it doesn't count the sales items towards the total.

Comment: So 1) cart needs to reach 10 items. 2) Then 10% off on any item not already on sale.

Comment: Correct. You're much more succinct than I ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on some research, I believe a custom [Adjuster](https://craftcommerce.com/docs/adjusters) is the way to solve this problem.

I created an adjuster with the following:

`craft/plugins/myplugin/MypluginPlugin.php`

```php
public function commerce_registerOrderAdjusters()
{
  return [
    401 => new \Commerce\Adjusters\Myplugin_TenpercentDiscount
  ];
}
```

`craft/plugins/myplugin/Adjusters/Myplugin_TenPercentDiscount.php`

```php
<?php

namespace Commerce\Adjusters;
use Craft\Commerce_LineItemModel;
use Craft\Commerce_OrderAdjustmentModel;
use Craft\Commerce_OrderModel;

class Myplugin_TenPercentDiscount implements Commerce_AdjusterInterface {

public function adjust(Commerce_OrderModel &$order, array $lineItems = []){

    if (empty($lineItems))
    {
        return [];
    }

    if ($order->totalQty >= 10)
    {
        $adjuster = new Commerce_OrderAdjustmentModel();

        $adjuster->type        = 'Item Discount';
        $adjuster->name        = '10% Off Items';
        $adjuster->description = 'Your order qualifies for a 10% discount on all non sale items because you are purchasing at least 10 products.';
        $adjuster->orderId     = $order->id;

        $amountOff = 0;
        foreach ($lineItems as $item)
        {
            if (empty($item->onSale))
            {
                $amountOff += ($item->subtotal + $item->discount) * .1;
            }
        }
        $amountOff = $amountOff * -1;

        $adjuster->amount      = $amountOff;
        $adjuster->optionsJson = ['lineItemsAffected' => null];
        $order->baseDiscount  += $amountOff;

        $adjuster->included = false;

        return [$adjuster];
    }
    return[];
}

}
```

Does anyone see any flaws with this approach?

Comment: Hi peter, I am struggling onto where I'd have to put this code. I've tried to put it under craft->plugins->Commerce->Adjusters and named it Myplugin_TenPercentDiscount.php. But that does not seem to work. Sorry, I am a bit lost in all of this.

Comment: Hi @outline4 -- You're close. You'll need to create your own plugin. I suggest using Plugin Factory for the scaffolding: https://pluginfactory.io/ and then you'll want the adjuster in the path: `craft/plugins/yourplugin/Adjusters/Yourplugin_Adjustername.php`

Comment: Forgot to add, you also need to register the adjuster, I updated my code above to show that